# Adding New Tab When Clicking an Item from a Tree Panel

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I'm new to EXT.NET and what I want is a simple event from an `<EXT:TreePanel>` and will reflect on an `<EXT:TabPanel>`.

For example I have this `<EXT:TreePanel>`:

```
<ext:TreePanel 
            ID="TreePanel1" 
            class="TP1" 
            runat="server" 
            Title="Sample List"
            Icon="Accept"
            Height="400"
            Width="250"
            UseArrows="true"
            AutoScroll="true"
            Animate="true"            
            HideHeaders="true"
            RootVisible="false">
            <Root>
                <ext:Node>
                    <Children>
                        <ext:Node Text="Employee Management" Icon=ApplicationHome Expandable=true Expanded=true >
                            <Children>
                                <ext:Node Text="List of Employee" Leaf="true" Icon=ApplicationFormMagnify />
                                <ext:Node Text="Add" Leaf="true" Icon=ApplicationFormAdd />
                                <ext:Node Text="Edit" Leaf="true" Icon=ApplicationFormDelete />
                            </Children>
                        </ext:Node>
                    </Children>
                </ext:Node>
            </Root>

            <ColumnModel>
                <Columns>
                    <ext:TreeColumn ID="TreeColumn1" runat="server" Flex="1" DataIndex="text" />
                    <ext:CommandColumn ID="CommandColumn1" runat="server" Width="40">
                        <Commands>
                            <ext:GridCommand CommandName="Edit" Icon="PageWhiteEdit" ToolTip-Text="Edit task" />
                        </Commands>
                        <PrepareToolbar Handler="return record.data.leaf;" />
                    </ext:CommandColumn>
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>

         </ext:TreePanel>
```

and the `<EXT:TabPanel>`:

```
<ext:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" Region="Center">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel5" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Title="Center" 
                        Border="false" 
                        BodyPadding="6"
                        Html="<h1>Viewport with BorderLayout</h1>"
                        />
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel6" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Title="Close Me" 
                        Closable="true" 
                        Border="false" 
                        BodyPadding="6"
                        Html="Closeable Tab"
                        />
                </Items>
            </ext:TabPanel>
```

When the user click on any item from the `<EXT:TreePanel>` I want it to create a new tab on the `<EXT:TabPanel>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. And it's exactly what I'm looking for. See it [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?20144-CLOSED-Add-tab-from-TreePanel-builded-in-code-behind)